# why is there an error when im calling a function on python 3.9

Tags: python

here is the "problem" line that gets an error every time i try and run it i defined main here is the function:

def main():
clock = pygame.time.Clock()                           problem line  if **name** ==  ("**main**'):
run = True                                                           main()
while run:
clock.tick(FPS)
for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
run = False
WIN.fill((BLUE))
pygame.display.update()
draw_window()
pygame.quit()

Comment: The formatting got messed up. Please [edit] to fix it. See [code formatting help](/editing-help#code) if needed. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're opening a string with double quotes and closing it with single quotes.

Replace `if __name__ == ("__main__'):` with one of the following:

```py
if __name__ == ("__main__"):
if __name__ == ('__main__'):
if __name__ == "__main__":
if __name__ == '__main__':
```